# NPE при попытке использовать обратный вызов

Tags: java, android, callback

имеется интерфейс для обратного вызова

```
 public interface Callback {

    void callingBack();

}
```

Класс наследующий интерфейс обратного вызова

```
 class MainThread extends Thread implements Callback {

    GameOverFragment gameOverFragment;

    MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MainGamePanel gamePanel) {
        super();
        gameOverFragment = new GameOverFragment();
        gameOverFragment.registerCallBack(this); 
    }

    @Override
    public void callingBack() {
       //код для обратного вызова
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // код выполняемый в доп.потоке
    }
}
```

и класс в котором делается обратный вызов

```
public class GameOverFragment extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
    private View form = null;
    Callback callback;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View form = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.gameoverfragment, null);

        return dialog;

    }


    public void registerCallBack(Callback callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface unused) {
        super.onDismiss(unused);
        callback.callingBack();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface unused) {
        super.onCancel(unused);
    }

}
```

Регистрация  gameOverFragment.registerCallBack(this); проходит. После по определенному условию показывается диалог. И по его закрытию должен отработать метод обратного вызова callback.callingBack(); но я получаю NPE именно на этапе закрытия диалога.
Стоит наверно добавить, что класс MainThread абстрактный, он имеет парочку абстрактных методов.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                          Process: example.igeniy, PID: 4058
                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                              at example.igeniy.GameOverFragment.onDismiss(GameOverFragment.java:230)
                                                              at android.app.Dialog$ListenersHandler.handleMessage(Dialog.java:1238)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Если убрать строку callback.callingBack(); то ошибки не будет, но тогда и нужный мне метод не отработает после закрытия диалога.  В момент вызова  callback действительно = null , но почему?  Поставил точку останова в момент когда передаю в callback экземпляр класса и видно , что он передается и callback не null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось я не доглядел , что я создавал GameOverFragment gameOverFragment; и передавал в него экземпляр класса, а сам ДиалогФрагмент вызывался совершено в другом классе и это уже вовсе не тот самый экземпляр.